# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument (AFTER escaping backslashes)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, escaping

I'm trying to create a pandas ExcelFile object, and I'm getting the following error on the last line of my code below: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`.

From what I understand this is caused by having backslashes in the file path, which Python interprets as an escape character-- but as you can see, I added in a call to `replace()` to replace single backslashes with double ones, which should escape them properly. Any ideas as to what else I can try?

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

#Prompts you to select a folder
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
directory = filedialog.askdirectory().replace('/', '\\')

#loops over files in folder, trying to create an ExcelFile object from each of them
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    full_path = os.path.join(directory, f).replace('\\', '\\\\')
    print(full_path)
    wkb = pd.ExcelFile(full_path)
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, I don't have a windows box to test this on right now, but last time I checked you can just use `/` instead of `\` even in windows

Comment: there is absolutely no need to convert `/` to `\`. Windows has supported the forward slash for many years.

Comment: I think I did that because os.path.join concatenates the two parts with a backslash so I did that to make it uniform. Either way, I just tried it with forward slashes and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, but the solution was not in my code. The file I was trying to access was in a synced Sharepoint folder, and sync was paused so I guess Python couldn't access the file (I found this out when I tried copying the file to a different folder and got an error popup saying "The Cloud File provider is not running"). I literally just had to turn syncing back on and it fixed everything. Totally not related to Python or anything-- although I wish that error message would've been more descriptive. :)